# C++ Deleting from a List with a start position and a end

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list, delete-operator

How I can delete from a List for example from positions 1 to 4?

I just solve this delete with 1 element from the List:

```
void delPos(int iPos) {
  ListElem *pElemToDelete = mpHead;
  for (int i = 0; i < iPos; ++i) {
    pElemToDelete = pElemToDelete->mpNext;
  }
  if (pElemToDelete != nullptr) {
    if (mpHead == pElemToDelete) {
      mpHead = pElemToDelete->mpNext;
      delete pElemToDelete;
    } else {
      for (ListElem *pTmp = mpHead; pTmp != nullptr; pTmp = pTmp->mpNext) {
        if (pTmp->mpNext == pElemToDelete) {
          pTmp->mpNext = pElemToDelete->mpNext;
          delete pElemToDelete;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And for position deleting (start to end) I got this:

```
void deleteElem(int start, int end) {
  ListElem *pTmp1 = m_pHead;
  ListElem *pTmp2 = m_pHead;
  for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
    if (i < start - 1) {
      if (pTmp1->m_pNext != nullptr) {
        pTmp1 = pTmp1->m_pNext;
      }
    }
    if (pTmp2->m_pNext != nullptr) {
      pTmp2 = pTmp2->m_pNext;
    }
  }
  if (start == 0) {
    m_pHead = pTmp2->m_pNext;
  } else {
    pTmp1->m_pNext = pTmp2->m_pNext;
  }
}
```

but it is not really deleted right? It just show the nextpointer to the right element. I try it like above with 1 element but it doesn't work.

Maybe you guys can give me some tips?

Comment: Do you implement that as homework/exercise or to figure out how a list can be implemented, or do you really need a list that you want to use?

Comment: It's not too obvious way of solving, but try to draw what you want with plain pen & paper, it'll give you thoughts on how your list is connected and what you want to achieve.

Comment: t.niese its a exercise for me to learn the basics of lists. And yes i need it as a list
@Artem Bondar yeah i did it.. my problem is im come from java there is a garbage collector so i just need to set the referenc of the pointer to the right place and it deletes the unuse elements of a list.. in c++ you need to delete by your own and its not the same process.. i want to delete from posistion 1 to 4 for example and the other ones should be displayed.

Comment: @MoFug -- Do you know how to delete an entire list?  It should be almost the same steps as deleting an entire list.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you mean something like this? ```ListElem* pTmp = mpHead;
   for(ListElem* pTmp = mpHead;pTmp != nullptr;pTmp = pTmp->mpNext) {
     delete pTmp;//
     return;
    }```

Comment: @MoFug -- No, that's wrong.  You are deleting the `pTmp` node, and then at the beginning of each iteration, you're trying to do `pTmp->mpNext` when `pTmp` has already been deleted.  You should work on figuring out how to delete your entire list first, let alone how to partially delete it.

Comment: not singly linked, but might be useful anyway https://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmm i try a bit arount ```void deleteFullList(){
   ListElem* pTmp = mpHead;
   ListElem* store;
   
   while(pTmp->mpNext!=nullptr){
    store = pTmp->mpNext;
    delete pTmp;
    pTmp = store;
   }
  }```but if i try to cout the list its a never ending loop.. but if i dont cout it, it says all good.. hm
but thannks you guys i try a bit around :) it give me some new ideas


sp2danny thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this function

```
void delPos(int iPos) {
  ListElem *pElemToDelete = mpHead;
  for (int i = 0; i < iPos; ++i) {
    pElemToDelete = pElemToDelete->mpNext;
  }
  //..
```

can invoke undefined behavior when `iPos` is greater than or equal to the number of nodes in the list.

The function can be implemented the following way

```
bool delPos( size_t iPos ) 
{
    ListElem **pElemToDelete = &mpHead;

    for ( ; pElemToDelete != nullptr && iPos != 0; --iPos )
    {
         pElemToDelete = &( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
    }

    bool success = pElemToDelete != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        ListElem *tmp  = *pElemToDelete;
        *pElemToDelete = ( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Now it is not difficult to implement the second function. I assume that the end position is not included in the range of the deleted nodes.

```
bool delPos( size_t iStart, size_t iEnd ) 
{
    bool success = iStart < iEnd;

    if ( success )
    {
        ListElem **pElemToDelete = &mpHead;

        size_t i = 0;

        for ( ; pElemToDelete != nullptr && i != iStart; ++i )
        {
            pElemToDelete = &( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
        }

        success = pElemToDelete != nullptr;

        if ( success )
        {
            for ( ; pElemToDelete != nullptr && i != iEnd; i++ )
            {
                ListElem *tmp  = *pElemToDelete;
                *pElemToDelete = ( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
                delete tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

class List
{
private:
    struct ListElem
    {
        int data;
        ListElem *mpNext;
    } *mpHead = nullptr;
public: 
    List() = default;

    void pushFront( int );

    bool delPos( size_t );
    bool delPos( size_t, size_t );

    std::ostream & printList( std::ostream & = std::cout ) const;
};


void List::pushFront( int data )
{
    mpHead = new ListElem { data, mpHead };
}

bool List::delPos( size_t iPos ) 
{
    ListElem **pElemToDelete = &mpHead;

    for ( ; pElemToDelete != nullptr && iPos != 0; --iPos )
    {
         pElemToDelete = &( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
    }

    bool success = pElemToDelete != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        ListElem *tmp  = *pElemToDelete;
        *pElemToDelete = ( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return success;
}

bool List::delPos( size_t iStart, size_t iEnd ) 
{
    bool success = iStart < iEnd;

    if ( success )
    {
        ListElem **pElemToDelete = &mpHead;

        size_t i = 0;

        for ( ; pElemToDelete != nullptr && i != iStart; ++i )
        {
            pElemToDelete = &( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
        }

        success = pElemToDelete != nullptr;

        if ( success )
        {
            for ( ; pElemToDelete != nullptr && i != iEnd; i++ )
            {
                ListElem *tmp  = *pElemToDelete;
                *pElemToDelete = ( *pElemToDelete )->mpNext;
                delete tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

std::ostream & List::printList( std::ostream &os ) const
{
    for ( ListElem *current = mpHead; current != nullptr; current = current->mpNext )
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';
    }

    return os << "nullptr";
}

int main() 
{
    List lst;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) lst.pushFront( i );

    lst.printList() << '\n';

    lst.delPos( 0 );

    lst.printList() << '\n';

    lst.delPos( 8 );

    lst.printList() << '\n';

    lst.delPos( 3, 5 );

    lst.printList() << '\n';

lst.delPos( 0, 6 );

lst.printList() << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 nullptr
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 nullptr
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 nullptr
8 7 6 3 2 1 nullptr
nullptr
```

Comment: thanks :) i understand what you mean but the doublepointer are very confusig for me. But i understand what you mean and it helps me very for my thought process

Comment: i try it only just with one pointer, but somehow it wont work for me.. maybe my brain just dont get it. Its almost the same with one pointer right? with no double

Comment: @MoFug With one pointer the functions will not work correctly. They will be unable to change at lest the head node.

Comment: ah, i mean can i do it without doublepointers?i mean i works.. but somehow my output shows me a for example i got 6 5 4 3 2 1 and delete from 1 to 2 position it shows me as output for like this 6 858124 3 2 1 nulltpr. somehow it adds something between the deleted nodes. May you know why? i change a bit your code ``` ListElem *pElemToDelete = mpHead;``` and added ```ListElem* storefirst = pElemToDelete;``` after the second if i just set ``` storefirst->mpNext = pElemToDelete;``` and adapt  the rest of the code.